# Toggle Slider do not change back icon correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am not getting this straight and would be very thankful for any help. I use toggle slider on my website and they almost do what I want. This is:

Changing Icon when clicked (from + to -), sliding down the content container
Closing an open container and changing back the icon to +, if another toggle link is clicked.

The problem I have is, that the icon of an open container is not changing back to +, if you click its toggle link again (instead of clicking another toggle link). Got it?

You can view this here:
http://nextree.ch/konzept/

Please click the panels and you will see. All is working fine, unless you click the same link that you opened, to close it.

This is the code for the feature, as it is right now:

```
 // Toggle Slides
$(function(){ // run after page loads
        //Switch the "Open" and "Close" state per click then slide up/down (depending on open/close state)
        $("p.trigger, h3.trigger").click(function(){
                $("p.trigger, h3.trigger").removeClass("active");
                $('.toggle_container').not($(this).next()).slideUp();
                $(this).addClass("active").next().slideToggle(500);
                return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
        });
});
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

This is the HTML of one of those toggle container

```
<div class="list">
<p class="trigger">
    <a href="#">All you need is Nextree…</a>
</p>
<div class="toggle_container">
    <div class="block clearfix">
    <p>denn es deckt alle wichtigen Geschäftsprozesse ab. Geniessen Sie die Vorteile der vollständigen Integration, die automatische Verlinkung von zusammenhängenden Informationen, den direkten Zugriff auf Dokumente – jederzeit und überall.
    </p>
    </div>
    <p class="toggle-close">
    <a href="#">Close</a>
    </p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is because you are doing $(this).addClass("active") at the end. So it does not matter if you open or close, you will add the active class to the item you just clicked at the end. So when something is open and you click it again, it will first remove the active class and close it, then add the active class again so the - sign is still shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
        $("p.trigger, h3.trigger").click(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                var hasActive = $this.hasClass('active');

                $("p.trigger, h3.trigger").removeClass("active");
                $('.toggle_container').not($this.next()).slideUp();
                if( !hasActive ) {
                   $this.addClass("active");
                }
                $this.next().slideToggle(500);
                return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
        });
```

This will only add active if current is not active. This is untested code, as long as you understand what I am trying to do, if there is an error in the code, you should be on the right track to solve it

Comment: This is so very perfect, works like a charme. Thank you sooooo much, I am very happy ;-)